# Log Data Analytics : Choice of Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql, mapreduce, relational-database

I am getting Log Data from various web applications in the following format:

```
Session    Timestamp    Event                Parameters
1          1            Started Session      
1          2            Logged In            Username:"user1"
2          3            Started Session
1          3            Started Challenge    title:"Challenge 1", level:"2"
2          4            Logged In            Username:"user2"
```

Now, a person wants to carry out analytics on this log data (And would like to receive it as a JSON blob after appropriate transformations). For example, he may want to receive a JSON blob where the Log Data is grouped by `Session` and `TimeFromSessionStart` and `CountOfEvents` are added before the data is sent so that he can carry out meaningful analysis. Here I should return:

```
[
  {
    "session":1,"CountOfEvents":3,"Actions":[{"TimeFromSessionStart":0,"Event":"Session Started"}, {"TimeFromSessionStart":1, "Event":"Logged In", "Username":"user1"}, {"TimeFromSessionStart":2, "Event":"Startd Challenge", "title":"Challenge 1", "level":"2" }]
  },
  { 
    "session":2, "CountOfEvents":2,"Actions":[{"TimeFromSessionStart":0,"Event":"Session     Started"}, {"TimeFromSessionStart":2, "Event":"Logged In", "Username":"user2"}] 
  }
]
```

Here, `TimeFromSessionStart`, `CountOfEvents` etc. [Let's call it synthetic additional data] will not be hard coded and I will make a web interface to allow the person to decide what kind of synthetic data he requires in the JSON blob. I would like to provide a good amount of flexibility to the person to decide what kind of synthetic data he wants in the JSON blob.

I am expecting the database to store around 1 Million rows and carry out transformations in a reasonable amount of time.

My question is regarding choice of Database. What will be the relative advantages and disadvantages of using SQL Database such as PostgreSQL v/s using NoSQL Database such as MongoDB. From whatever I have read till now, I think that NoSQL may not be able to provide enough flexibility of adding additional synthetic data. On the other hand, I may face issues of flexibility in data representation if I use SQL Database.

I think the storage requirement for both MongoDB and PostgreSQL will be comparable since I will have to build similar indices (probably!) in both situations to speed up querying.

If I use PostgreSQL, I can store the data in the following manner:
`Session` and `Event` can be `string`, `Timestamp` can be `date` and `Parameters` can be `hstore`(key value pairs available in PostgreSQL). After that, I can use SQL queries to compute the synthetic (or additional) data, store it temporarily in variables in a Rails Application (which will interact with PostgreSQL database and act as interface for the person who wants the JSON blob) and create JSON blob from it.

Another possible approach is to use MongoDB for storing the log data and use [Mongoid](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid) as an interface with Rails application if I can get enough flexibility of adding additional synthetic data for analytics and some performance/storage improvements over PostgreSQL. But, in this case, I am not clear of what will be the best way to store log data in MongoDB. Also, I read that MongoDB will be somewhat slower than PostgreSQL and is mainly meant to run in background.

*Edit:*
From whatever I have read in the past few days, Apache Hadoop seems to be a good choice as well because of it's greater speed over MongoDB (being multi-threaded).

**Edit:**
I am not asking for opinions and would like to know the specific advantages or disadvantages of using a particular approach. Therefore, I don't think that the question is opinion based.

Comment: not everything you've read is accurate. MongoDB is neither single-threaded nor is it meant to run in "background".

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I read that `MongoDB: The Definitive Guide` says that `The price of using MapReduce is speed: group is not particularly speedy, but MapReduce is slower and is not supposed to be used in “real time.” You run MapReduce as a background job, it creates a collection of results, and then you can query that collection in real time.`

Comment: MongoDB is a lot more than MapReduce, in fact, MR is a somewhat marginal feature of it, you should not even be using map-reduce - you should use aggregation framework which runs on the server (not in JS) and is an order of magnitude faster than map-reduce.

Comment: you said you get log data from various applications, but you don't show application id anywhere in your examples.  do you expect for queries to be across all applications, or just for specific ones or ???

Comment: Yes, the queries will be across all applications (Also, I can add an application id if required without much problem). I don't know how I should store the log data if I use MongoDB. I mean, how should the `Parameters` be represented so that they can be partially indexed later on to increase query speed for certain types of queries [Eg. those concerned with username]? Also are there any disadvantages of MongoDB compared to PostgreSQL for my use case?

Comment: those questions are quite involved and open ended - it'd be helpful to narrow the scope of the discussion somewhat, but I'll add an answer which will at least touch on your questions (with pointers for further reading).

Comment: you can also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594458/which-database-to-choose-cassandra-mongodb-for-storing-and-querying-event though it's quite outdated, since this was before MongoDB supported aggregations natively, the general discussion is quite on point.

Comment: PostgreSQL does have good support for JSON, and improved storage efficiency in 9.4 (now in beta - http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1522/ ). Functions available as of now - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html. I guess you have to look at the functions available in NoSQL and traditional databases. Also look at possible requirements for joining data, filtering data etc. Traditional databases do have a number of functions available to transform data.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out logstash / kibana from elasticsearch.  The primary use case for that stack is collecting log data, storing it, analyzing it.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/
http://www.elasticsearch.org/videos/kibana-logstash/

Mongo is a good choice too if you are looking at building it all yourself, but I think you could find that the products from elasticsearch very well could solve your needs and allow the integration you need.

Comment: Highly recommend something like logstash and using the time saved to add other features like graphs. ( http://graphite.wikidot.com/ or http://grafana.org/)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is well suited to your task and its document storage is more flexible than the rigid SQL table structure.
Below, please find a working test using Mongoid
that demonstrates comprehension of your log data input,
easy storage as documents in a MongoDB collection,
and analytics using MongoDB's aggregation framework.
I've chosen to put the parameters in a sub-document.
This matches your sample input table more closely and simplifies the pipeline.
The resulting JSON is slightly modified,
but all of the specified calculations, data, and grouping is present.
I've added a test for an index on parameter Username that demonstrates an index on a subdoc field.
This is adequate for specific fields that you want to index,
but a completely general index can't be done on keys, you would have to restructure to values.

I hope that this helps and that you like it.

test/unit/log_data_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

class LogDataTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    LogData.delete_all
    @log_data_analysis_pipeline = [
        {'$group' => {
            '_id' => '$session',
            'session' => {'$first' => '$session'},
            'CountOfEvents' => {'$sum' => 1},
            'timestamp0' => {'$first' => '$timestamp'},
            'Actions' => {
                '$push' => {
                    'timestamp' => '$timestamp',
                    'event' => '$event',
                    'parameters' => '$parameters'}}}},
        {'$project' => {
            '_id' => 0,
            'session' => '$session',
            'CountOfEvents' => '$CountOfEvents',
            'Actions' => {
                '$map' => { 'input' => "$Actions", 'as' => 'action',
                            'in' => {
                                'TimeFromSessionStart' => {
                                    '$subtract' => ['$$action.timestamp', '$timestamp0']},
                                'event' => '$$action.event',
                                'parameters' => '$$action.parameters'
                            }}}}
        }
    ]
    @key_names = %w(session timestamp event parameters)
    @log_data = <<-EOT.gsub(/^\s+/, '').split(/\n/)
    1          1            Started Session
    1          2            Logged In            Username:"user1"
    2          3            Started Session
    1          3            Started Challenge    title:"Challenge 1", level:"2"
    2          4            Logged In            Username:"user2"
    EOT
    docs = @log_data.collect{|line| line_to_doc(line)}
    LogData.create(docs)
    assert_equal(docs.size, LogData.count)
    puts
  end
  def line_to_doc(line)
    doc = Hash[*@key_names.zip(line.split(/  +/)).flatten]
    doc['session'] = doc['session'].to_i
    doc['timestamp'] = doc['timestamp'].to_i
    doc['parameters'] = eval("{#{doc['parameters']}}") if doc['parameters']
    doc
  end
  test "versions" do
    puts "Mongoid version: #{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped version: #{Moped::VERSION}"
    puts "MongoDB version: #{LogData.collection.database.command({:buildinfo => 1})['version']}"
  end
  test "log data analytics" do
    pp LogData.all.to_a
    result = LogData.collection.aggregate(@log_data_analysis_pipeline)
    json = <<-EOT
        [
            {
                "session":1,"CountOfEvents":3,"Actions":[{"TimeFromSessionStart":0,"Event":"Session Started"}, {"TimeFromSessionStart":1, "Event":"Logged In", "Username":"user1"}, {"TimeFromSessionStart":2, "Event":"Started Challenge", "title":"Challenge 1", "level":"2" }]
            },
            {
                "session":2, "CountOfEvents":2,"Actions":[{"TimeFromSessionStart":0,"Event":"Session Started"}, {"TimeFromSessionStart":2, "Event":"Logged In", "Username":"user2"}]
            }
        ]
    EOT
    puts JSON.pretty_generate(result)
  end
  test "explain" do
    LogData.collection.indexes.create('parameters.Username' => 1)
    pp LogData.collection.find({'parameters.Username' => 'user2'}).to_a
    pp LogData.collection.find({'parameters.Username' => 'user2'}).explain['cursor']
  end
end
```

app/models/log_data.rb

```
class LogData
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :session, type: Integer
  field :timestamp, type: Integer
  field :event, type: String
  field :parameters, type: Hash
end
```

$ rake test

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[1/3] LogDataTest#test_explain
[{"_id"=>"537258257f11ba8f03000005",
  "session"=>2,
  "timestamp"=>4,
  "event"=>"Logged In",
  "parameters"=>{"Username"=>"user2"}}]
"BtreeCursor parameters.Username_1"
[2/3] LogDataTest#test_log_data_analytics      
[#<LogData _id: 537258257f11ba8f03000006, session: 1, timestamp: 1, event: "Started Session", parameters: nil>,
 #<LogData _id: 537258257f11ba8f03000007, session: 1, timestamp: 2, event: "Logged In", parameters: {"Username"=>"user1"}>,
 #<LogData _id: 537258257f11ba8f03000008, session: 2, timestamp: 3, event: "Started Session", parameters: nil>,
 #<LogData _id: 537258257f11ba8f03000009, session: 1, timestamp: 3, event: "Started Challenge", parameters: {"title"=>"Challenge 1", "level"=>"2"}>,
 #<LogData _id: 537258257f11ba8f0300000a, session: 2, timestamp: 4, event: "Logged In", parameters: {"Username"=>"user2"}>]
[
  {
    "session": 2,
    "CountOfEvents": 2,
    "Actions": [
      {
        "TimeFromSessionStart": 0,
        "event": "Started Session",
        "parameters": null
      },
      {
        "TimeFromSessionStart": 1,
        "event": "Logged In",
        "parameters": {
          "Username": "user2"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "session": 1,
    "CountOfEvents": 3,
    "Actions": [
      {
        "TimeFromSessionStart": 0,
        "event": "Started Session",
        "parameters": null
      },
      {
        "TimeFromSessionStart": 1,
        "event": "Logged In",
        "parameters": {
          "Username": "user1"
        }
      },
      {
        "TimeFromSessionStart": 2,
        "event": "Started Challenge",
        "parameters": {
          "title": "Challenge 1",
          "level": "2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
[3/3] LogDataTest#test_versions                           
Mongoid version: 3.1.6
Moped version: 1.5.2
MongoDB version: 2.6.1
Finished tests in 0.083465s, 35.9432 tests/s, 35.9432 assertions/s.
3 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks very much for the detailed answer. I still have a doubt. You seem to have hard coded `CountOfEvents` and `TimeFromSessionStart` but I want more flexibility over the synthetic additional data to be added. For eg. what if the person wants count of specific event in output. Eg. count of `Started Challenge` or he wants number of events performed out of `Started Challenge`, `Changed Gravity`. I was thinking of making functions which act as templates, accept parameters, compute the synthetic data. Later, the synthetic data may be used to form the JSON blob.

Comment: Is PostgreSQL better in this scenario or would MongoDB be still better for this case? With MongoDB, I can use Mongoid for querying however I suspect that PostgreSQL will probably be faster with such queries (with most of them being aggregation based). Any advice/opinion on this would be great. Anyways, I will still give you the bounty because your answer seems to most detailed and helpful and it must have taken a lot of effort!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is an ideal database for this.

1. Create a collection for your raw log data.
2. Use one of Mongo's powerful aggregation tools, and output the aggregated data to another collection (or multiple output collections, if you want different buckets or views of the raw data)

You can either do the agg offline, with a set of pre-determined possibilities that users can pull from, or do it on demand/ad hoc, if you can tolerate some latency in your response.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

Comment: Hi, How should I store the log data in MongoDB. I mean, how should the `Parameters` be represented so that they can be partially indexed later on to increase query speed for certain types of queries?